# Custom validator is not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a gridview called `gv1`. There is checkbox inside it, and atleast 1 checkbox must be checked for processing. I have custom validation for it but it is not working. Please take a look at below,

Custom Validator

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="vldItemCus"
    ClientValidationFunction="ValidateSelection"
    Display="None" ErrorMessage="Select atleast one item for update" ValidationGroup="Update"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Validation Summary

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="vldSummary" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="True" ShowSummary="False" ValidationGroup="Update"></asp:ValidationSummary>
```

Javascript Function

```
function ValidateSelection(source, args) {
    var found = 0;
    $('#gv1 input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            found = 1;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (found == 1) {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Have you set a js break point in `ValidateSelection`?

Comment: Yes, function called. I tried alert inside function and it worked.

Comment: I think you need to set `ControlToValidate` of the validator for it to work correctly

Comment: @Andrei: a CustomValidator is the only validator where you can omit the ControlToValidate. You can even use it to validate multiple controls at once.

Comment: Well. I don't think so. Custom validator does not require `ControlToValidate` property.

Comment: Piyush, are you sure the `ClientID` of your gridview resolves to `gv1`? Are there any naming containers in its ancestor chain?

Comment: If you can debug the js function, what happens there? You're currently the only one who knows it.

Comment: Oh yes, I checked view source of my page and found that `gv1` rendered with id `ctl00_gv1`, so I need to update my javascript function accordingly. I updated and it worked. Sorry to bother you guys. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed function as below,

```
function ValidateSelection(source, args) {
    var found = 0;
    $('#<%= gv1.ClientID %> input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            found = 1;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (found == 1) {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: If you, for whatever reason, put gridview in a panel, this will break. Better use ClientID property